# RingCentral API Need Help Finding QUEUE ACTIVITY data

Tags: api, calllog, ringcentral, call-queue

I don't know what report contains the QUEUE ACTIVITY data that is on the web portal.  I want to pull that information for my own use. For instance where do I find "time till answered".  It's not in the call-log report as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I work for RingCentral. While RingCentral Live Reports Queue Activity Report has an Average Time to Answer dashboard item, the API doesn't have this information yet.

We will look at adding this information to the `call-log` API data. Let us know if you would like this data any other way, e.g. average time to answer per queue event data.

Comment: Anything extra would be a bonus. Do you have any way to send automated reports from your online dashboard in the meantime?  Or is this a quick add to the api?

Comment: Both automated reports and the API are under consideration. For more information on schedule and capabilities, you can reach out to me at the email address on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

We recently launched a new event stream called CSN (Call Session Notification). This event stream emits events for all stages of the call from Proceeding State to Answered to Disconnected and you can use that to calculate the time difference.

The Documentation is at:

https://ringcentral-api-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/active_call_control_overview/

These are Advanced APIs and you would need an additional permission "Telephony Sessions" , to add that permissions to your app please email to devsupport@ringcentral.com with your Org and App details and they will add the permission. Once Added you can add the event filter `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/telephony/sessions` (Account level) or even at an extension level.

I have a sample a sample App where I have used the CSN to get , calculate the number of calls on Hold and display it : https://github.com/dibyenduroy/ringcentral_callqueue_monitoring_app

Hope this helps.